# Retrieve Row Count on SSRS / MySQL

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, rowcount

I'm using SSRS linked to MySQL by ODBC. My query sums the payment amount by customer, and sorts by amount desc. I want to use this to create a LeaderBoard in SSRS, showing the Rank, and only including the top 10 customers.

**Option 1:**
Do an additional query on my group query in SQL, adding the Row Number.

**Option 2:**
Add a calculated field in SSRS.

Option 1 seemed bulky, so started with Option 2; I added a calculated field to the dataset called "Rank", defined as `=RowNumber("DataSet1")`

I added a calculated field to the dataset called "Rank", defined as: =RowNumber("DataSet1")

But I got the following error:

> The expression used for the calculated field 'Rank' includes an aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.

So, I then added it to the actual tablix, and I was able to get the Rank to show correctly.
(When I did this, it automatically added an extra column to my dataset.

I then wanted to filter the top 10 customers.

I first tried by "bottom 10" on this new field, but it didn't work. (Seems this field is all zeros in the actual dataset.)

I then tried by "top 10" on the payment amount, but received an error that the filter only supports Integers.

So I tried to convert the payment amount to Integer in MySQL, using CAST and Convert, but they don't support conversion to Integer, and SSRS didn't like 'SIGNED' or any of the other options.

I then started trying Option 1, which was building the query into MySQL.
I added:

```
SET @rank=0; 
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS Rank, ...
```

This works in MySQL, but I get an error when I paste that query into the report definition on SSRS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting @rank=0 in a separate statement, try setting it in a subquery cross-joined to the main query - like so:

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS Rank, ...
FROM (SELECT @rank:= 0) r
CROSS JOIN ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! (I had to define a default value for the parameter in the report definition.) However, I'm still not able to filter the top 10, because SSRS also sees the Rank as Float, and not Integer. I could do limit in MySQL, but I want to use the same dataset in a few tables in the report. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I did a limit 10 in MySQL, which gives the top 10 customers. And in a second tablix used a filter where Rank = 1 which SSRS accepted even though Rank was a float. But surely there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: @user2542009: I should have thought of `limit 10`, but I guess I had tunnel vision about doing the selection in SSRS. *"But surely there's a better way of doing this"* - what, selecting the top 10 in one tablix and the top 1 in another? The method you are using seems pretty good; can you explain in what way you think it cold be better?